# How can I prevent Microsoft Edge from automatically adding favorites?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Every now and then Microsoft Edge adds new favorites to my list, based on the number of visits to that page I guess. Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: What version of Edge? Because I only use Edge and this absolutely is NOT happening on the current version.  Which means you likely have an extension installed that is doing this.

Comment: Version 102.0.1245.30 (Officiële build) (64-bits). I do not have any extension installed as far as I know.